# Не выводятся значения переменных внутри div

Tags: php

Не выводятся значения переменных внутри div. Простой вывод через echo работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка?
Часть кода:

```html
 while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
              $start=($result['create_date']);
              $user_uid=($result['uid']);
              $user_id=($result['id']);
              $stat=($result['status']);
              $reg_lid=($result['lid']);
              $amount=($result['amount_value']);
              $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['create_date']));
      $referrals_amount=($result['referrals_amount']);  
     
             
      if ($user_uid==$cur_id&&($reg_lid['lid']==1)) {
            $proc = 25;
            $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
            $proc = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc;
            $proc_d = ($amount+$referrals_amount)/100*$proc_d;
          $amount_all = $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
            $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc;
            $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $referrals_amount + $proc_d;
            round ($amountWithPct_all);
            round ($amountWithPct_d);
         //Проверяем вывод
        echo " {$start}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$datediff}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$amount}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$referrals_amount}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$proc_d}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$amount_all}<br/>"; //выводится
        echo "{$amountWithPct_all}<br/><br/>"; //выводится
         
              echo      '<div class="uap-row">
        <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab1">
            <div class="uap-account-no-box" style="padding-left:0px;">
             <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
                  <div class="uap-count"> <?php echo "{$datediff}" ?> </div> /* не выводится */
                <div class="uap-detail">Прошло дней</div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>'
```

Не выводится в этой части:

```html
<div class="uap-count"> <?php echo "{$datediff}" ?> </div> /* не выводится */
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось очень просто.

```html
<div class="uap-count"> ' . $datediff . ' </div>
```

И проблемы больше нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы выводите кусок HTML через `echo` вам не нужно указывать внутри него `<?php echo...` это отобразится как строка. Вместо этого сделайте конкатенацию:

```
echo      '<div class="uap-row">
        <div class="uapcol-md-4 uap-account-overview-tab1">
            <div class="uap-account-no-box" style="padding-left:0px;">
             <div class="uap-account-no-box-inside">
                  <div class="uap-count">' . $datediff . '</div> /* не выводится */
                <div class="uap-detail">Прошло дней</div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>'
```